# How can I implement STARTTLS on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, starttls

I would like to implement [STARTTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2595) in an iOS application but I'm having trouble figuring out from the documentation how to do it.

So far I have:

- I create the socket with `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` and open the streams:

  ```
   CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(
           NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)host, port,
           &read_stream, &write_stream
   );

   reader = objc_retainedObject(read_stream);
   [ reader setDelegate:self ];
   [ reader scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode ];
   [ reader open ];

   writer = objc_retainedObject(write_stream);
   [ writer setDelegate:self ];
   [ writer scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode ];
   [ writer open ];
  ```
- I get the right callbacks when data are available on the streams so the connection is working.
- I successfully interact with the server in plain text and negociate  STARTTLS.
- Eventually, the server sends the go-ahead for STARTTLS:

  ```
   . OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
  ```

Now it is time to upgrade the socket form plaintext to TLS. **What do I do next?**

I thought I should do this as per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html):

```
[ reader setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey ];
[ writer setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey ];
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not surprised that it doesn't work since the documentation says quite clearly:

> [You must set the property before you open the stream.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html)

Yet of course the stream must be already opened in this case since it is used to conduct the plaintext STARTTLS negociation!

I cannot find any documentation on how to upgrade a socket from plaintext to SSL or perhaps how to layer a new set of SSL-encrypted streams on top of a set of input&output plaintext streams.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it for your own protocol, or something well established, like SMTP, IMAP, ...?

Comment: @Bruno, it is for IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any way to implement STARTTLS using the high-level [CFStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/) API. There is [CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket) which allows you to connect your own socket and then apply TLS to it afterwards, but there is no way to get the library to verify the remote host name against the certificate host name.

The only way to do it appears to be using this much lower level library: [Secure Transport Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/).